# PSQL problem joining multiple tables (MIMIC II database)

Tags: mysql, join, psql

I have a patients database with multiple tables, and I need to join specific columns (pre-processed) from different tables in a results table. Here's how I do it:

```
SELECT d_patients.subject_id, icustay_detail.subject_icustay_seq,
icustay_detail.icustay_id,
icustay_detail.icustay_admit_age, d_patients.sex, 
icustay_detail.icustay_los/(60*24) los,
icustay_detail.weight_first/POWER(icustay_detail.height/100,2) bmi,
COALESCE( a.additives, 0 ) as additives,
COALESCE( p.procedureevents, 0 ) as procedureevents,
COALESCE( d.duration, 0 ) as duration,
COALESCE ( m.medications,0 ) as medications
FROM icustay_detail
INNER JOIN d_patients 
 ON icustay_detail.subject_id = d_patients.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, count(*) as additives 
    FROM additives 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) a
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = a.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, count(*) as procedureevents 
    FROM procedureevents 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) p
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = p.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, SUM(duration) as duration 
    FROM a_meddurations 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) d
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = d.subject_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT icustay_id, COUNT(DISTINCT solutionid)
    AS medications
    FROM medevents 
    GROUP BY icustay_id
    ) m
ON icustay_detail.icustay_id = m.icustay_id;
```

Up until here, the code works fine and the resulting table is the following

```
subject_id | subject_icustay_seq | icustay_id | icustay_admit_age | sex |         los          |       bmi        | additives | procedureevents | duration | medications 
------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+-----+----------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+-------------
          3 |                   1 |          4 |          76.52892 | M   |     6.06458333333333 |   30.18767669244 |        10 |               6 |    59145 |           2
         12 |                   1 |         13 |          72.36841 | M   |     7.63472222222222 |                  |         3 |              10 |    15092 |           2
         21 |                   1 |         23 |          87.43771 | M   |     5.90208333333333 | 21.3569005167836 |         7 |              15 |        0 |           1
         21 |                   2 |         24 |          87.82761 | M   |     8.36527777777778 |                  |         7 |              15 |        0 |           1
         26 |                   1 |         29 |          72.00637 | M   |     2.47569444444444 |                  |         0 |               2 |        0 |           0
         31 |                   1 |         34 |          72.26327 | M   |     7.93819444444444 |   22.12581585657 |         6 |               6 |    18316 |           2
         37 |                   1 |         41 |          68.93134 | M   |     1.13958333333333 |                  |         0 |               2 |        0 |           0
         56 |                   1 |         62 |           90.6427 | F   |     1.84930555555556 |                  |         3 |               2 |        0 |           0
         61 |                   1 |         67 |          54.72569 | M   |     2.55972222222222 |  18.168292503669 |         1 |              15 |        0 |           0
         61 |                   2 |         68 |            55.249 | M   |     2.04791666666667 |                  |         1 |              15 |        0 |           1
         61 |                   3 |         69 |          55.26185 | M   |  0.00277777777777778 |                  |         1 |              15 |        0 |           0
         67 |                   1 |         76 |          73.48396 | M   |    0.214583333333333 | 23.8462015385569 |         2 |               1 |      160 |           1
         78 |                   1 |         89 |          48.62681 | M   |     1.48958333333333 |                  |         1 |               1 |     2125 |           1
         83 |                   1 |         94 |          65.54958 | F   |     2.30902777777778 |                  |         0 |               3 |        0 |           0
         94 |                   1 |        107 |          74.43468 | M   |     1.09861111111111 |                  |        13 |              12 |        0 |           2
         94 |                   2 |        108 |          74.95603 | M   |     22.8979166666667 |                  |        13 |              12 |        0 |           2
        105 |                   1 |        121 |          35.33793 | F   |     4.99722222222222 |                  |         2 |               0 |        0 |           0
        105 |                   2 |        122 |           35.4088 | F   |     1.61944444444444 |                  |         2 |               0 |        0 |           0
        106 |                   1 |        123 |           35.6095 | M   |               6.1625 | 22.4312567927803 |         5 |               1 |        0 |           3
        112 |                   1 |        136 |          91.96166 | M   |    0.840277777777778 |                  |         5 |               8 |        0 |           0
        112 |                   2 |        137 |             94.25 | M   |     1.13888888888889 |                  |         5 |               8 |        0 |           2
```

The problem is when I try to add another column (abnormal) from another table (labevents), which is adding this part:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, round((COUNT(flag) * 100)::numeric / COUNT(*), 2) as abnormal 
    FROM labevents 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) ab
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = ab.subject_id
```

The resulting code is the following:

```
SELECT d_patients.subject_id, icustay_detail.subject_icustay_seq,
icustay_detail.icustay_id,
icustay_detail.icustay_admit_age, d_patients.sex, 
icustay_detail.icustay_los/(60*24) los,
icustay_detail.weight_first/POWER(icustay_detail.height/100,2) bmi,
COALESCE( a.additives, 0 ) as additives,
COALESCE( p.procedureevents, 0 ) as procedureevents,
COALESCE( d.duration, 0 ) as duration,
COALESCE( ab.abnormal, 0 ) as abnormal,
COALESCE( m.medications,0 ) as medications
FROM icustay_detail 
INNER JOIN d_patients 
 ON icustay_detail.subject_id = d_patients.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, count(*) as additives 
    FROM additives 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) a
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = a.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, count(*) as procedureevents 
    FROM procedureevents 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) p
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = p.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, SUM(duration) as duration 
    FROM a_meddurations 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) d
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = d.subject_id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT subject_id, round((COUNT(flag) * 100)::numeric / COUNT(*), 2) as abnormal 
    FROM labevents 
    GROUP BY subject_id
    ) ab
ON icustay_detail.subject_id = ab.subject_id
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT icustay_id, COUNT(DISTINCT solutionid)
    AS medications
    FROM medevents 
    GROUP BY icustay_id
    ) m
ON icustay_detail.icustay_id = m.icustay_id;
```

What happens is that the patient rows with 0 value in the "medications" column are removed, and I don't know why. The resulting table is this one:

```
subject_id | subject_icustay_seq | icustay_id | icustay_admit_age | sex |         los          |       bmi        | additives | procedureevents | duration | abnormal | medications 
------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+-----+----------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------
          3 |                   1 |          4 |          76.52892 | M   |     6.06458333333333 |   30.18767669244 |        10 |               6 |    59145 |    23.15 |           2
         12 |                   1 |         13 |          72.36841 | M   |     7.63472222222222 |                  |         3 |              10 |    15092 |    41.85 |           2
         21 |                   1 |         23 |          87.43771 | M   |     5.90208333333333 | 21.3569005167836 |         7 |              15 |        0 |    43.74 |           1
         21 |                   2 |         24 |          87.82761 | M   |     8.36527777777778 |                  |         7 |              15 |        0 |    43.74 |           1
         31 |                   1 |         34 |          72.26327 | M   |     7.93819444444444 |   22.12581585657 |         6 |               6 |    18316 |    26.69 |           2
         61 |                   2 |         68 |            55.249 | M   |     2.04791666666667 |                  |         1 |              15 |        0 |    41.63 |           1
         67 |                   1 |         76 |          73.48396 | M   |    0.214583333333333 | 23.8462015385569 |         2 |               1 |      160 |    29.73 |           1
         78 |                   1 |         89 |          48.62681 | M   |     1.48958333333333 |                  |         1 |               1 |     2125 |    35.75 |           1
         94 |                   1 |        107 |          74.43468 | M   |     1.09861111111111 |                  |        13 |              12 |        0 |    34.10 |           2
         94 |                   2 |        108 |          74.95603 | M   |     22.8979166666667 |                  |        13 |              12 |        0 |    34.10 |           2
        106 |                   1 |        123 |           35.6095 | M   |               6.1625 | 22.4312567927803 |         5 |               1 |        0 |    37.67 |           3
        112 |                   2 |        137 |             94.25 | M   |     1.13888888888889 |                  |         5 |               8 |        0 |    33.67 |           2
        117 |                   1 |        143 |           49.2842 | F   |     1.32013888888889 |                  |        14 |              15 |    42785 |    47.76 |           1
        117 |                   2 |        144 |          49.89653 | F   |     13.2493055555556 | 40.9070642360035 |        14 |              15 |    42785 |    47.76 |           3
        124 |                   1 |        151 |          69.63652 | M   |     3.91111111111111 | 22.1382505356903 |         7 |               8 |     8560 |    24.24 |           1
        124 |                   2 |        152 |          71.07388 | M   |     7.18958333333333 |                  |         7 |               8 |     8560 |    24.24 |           1
        146 |                   1 |        181 |          85.56421 | M   |     7.57013888888889 | 34.7959879593229 |        11 |               9 |    32648 |    35.88 |           2
        148 |                   1 |        183 |           78.1597 | F   |     15.2958333333333 |                  |         7 |               7 |  2826493 |    36.68 |           3
        150 |                   1 |        185 |          37.82158 | F   |     2.26180555555556 | 14.2542487150986 |         1 |               4 |     3083 |    23.10 |           1
        157 |                   2 |        195 |          80.53706 | M   |     4.11944444444444 |                  |         6 |              11 |        0 |    33.84 |           2
```

Please let me know if you need the specific content of the tables to try to understand the error. Thank you so much in advance.

Best,

Guille